# Wrong "edit your answer draft" after submit

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, draft

I just posted an answer twice (in two different versions) after I got the footer as displayed in the screenshot:

[image: bug]

Could you please fix this? (I'm part of the beta, but this is since last year I guess)

Comment: Are you saying that the draft indicator didn't go away after you submitted your post?

Comment: Yes so it is. I posted an answer then I added another sentence and there was surprisingly that editing hint. At first I thought that I pressed by accident on draft so I clicked on the banner and pressed directly on submit. After that I created a copy of my initial answer. Ah and after posting those two answers the banner was still there.

Comment: Gotcha, looking into this now.

Comment: @Kasra [it just happened again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248485/answer-from-app-is-both-posted-and-saved-as-a-draft), any updates?

Comment: The next update coming out Friday or Monday should fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in version 1.0.57 being pushed to the Play Store as we speak.

Comment: Great I'll check the update tomorrow.