# Answer from app is both posted and saved as a draft

Tags: bug, android-app, draft

I posted an answer from the Android app and it went back to the question, my answer wasn't there and I had a notification at the bottom saying I still have a draft of my answer.

So I opened the draft and submitted the answer again. Now I saw that both the previous submission and the current one went through and there was no draft notification.

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28483237/885318) (I deleted the second answer)